# Fetching paginated data from API, how can I get all pages in one clean .json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

So let me start off by saying that as of 3 hours ago, I knew nothing about Python. I've been learning as I go. I've been able to connect to the API I am working with, create and refresh oAuth2.0 tokens and make successful requests. I've saved those requests to .json files.

The next step was to loop my request and get ALL of the data (the API has a limit = 100). I've come up with a way to make that work, however, when it comes to writing to the .json file... I have some issues.

It writes fine, and it appends each step of the loop no problem. The issue is, it's adding the open and close portions of the .json every time. So when I try to use the data, I just get errors saying there's unexpected data after the file should have ended.

So my question is... how can I gather all of these paginated results and write them to one properly formatted .json?

Here's my initial request for data:

```
# making the initial request
url = my_url
headers = {
    "Authorization": token_type + SPACE + access_token, 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
response = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
# print(response.text)

nextsetup = response.json()
next = nextsetup['@attributes']['next']

#write response to file
writeFile =open('items.json', 'w')
writeFile.write(response.text)
writeFile.close()
```

Here's my loop:

```
while next:
    url = next
    headers = {
    "Authorization": token_type + SPACE + access_token, 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    responseloop = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    nextsetup = responseloop.json()
    next = nextsetup['@attributes']['next']
    
    print("page: ", page) #printing just to show me the loop is still running
    page = page+1

    #write response to file
    writeFile =open('C:/Users/apedd/Documents/LightspeedAPI/items.json', 'a')
    writeFile.write(response.text)
    writeFile.close()
```

I know it's messy, again I'm learning and I've used extra variables and steps I probably don't need as I have been trying other methods to get the output I need. This code "works" in that it gets all of the data and it saves it all... but it's adding things together as if I took several .json files and just copy/pasted the plain text into one big .json. Giving me error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 75498 of the JSON data
```

## Edit:

I've done some more learning and research and changed my approach. Here's my new code:

```
# making the initial request
def main_request(url, headers=headers):
    response = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

data = main_request(url, headers=headers)

next = data['@attributes']['next']
items = data['Item']

print("initial request complete, loop starting")

#loop while next exists
while next:
    url = next
    def main_request(url, headers=headers):
        response = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        return response.json()
        
    dataloop = main_request(url, headers=headers)
    next = dataloop['@attributes']['next']
    items.append(dataloop['Item'])
    print("page: ", page)
    page = page+1

#print results as a string to find errors
itemsstr = str(items)
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(itemsstr)

#Save results to .csv
outputcsv = pd.DataFrame(items)
outputcsv.to_csv("items.csv", index="ItemID")
```

If I run just the initial request part of my code and then go straight to converting to .csv... everything works great. But when I add in my loop to get the remainder of the data, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lightspeed.py", line 113, in <module>
    outputcsv = pd.DataFrame(items)
  File "---frame.py", line 721, in __init__
    arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 519, in nested_data_to_arrays
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 875, in to_arrays
    arr, columns = _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 960, in _list_of_dict_to_arrays
    pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 403, in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 958, in <genexpr>
    gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Here's the first two results in the output that works:

```
[{
    'itemID': '1',
    'systemSku': '210000000001',
    'defaultCost': '0',
    'avgCost': '0',
    'discountable': 'true',
    'tax': 'true',
    'archived': 'false',
    'itemType': 'non_inventory',
    'serialized': 'false',
    'description': 'Shipping',
    'modelYear': '0',
    'upc': '',
    'ean': '',
    'customSku': '',
    'manufacturerSku': '',
    'createTime': '2019-10-09T13:35:47+00:00',
    'timeStamp': '2021-02-08T13:56:37+00:00',
    'publishToEcom': 'true',
    'categoryID': '0',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '0',
    'manufacturerID': '0',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '0',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}, {
    'itemID': '4',
    'systemSku': '210000000004',
    'defaultCost': '0.1',
    'avgCost': '0',
    'discountable': 'true',
    'tax': 'true',
    'archived': 'false',
    'itemType': 'non_inventory',
    'serialized': 'false',
    'description': 'description',
    'modelYear': '0',
    'upc': '',
    'ean': '',
    'customSku': '',
    'manufacturerSku': '',
    'createTime': '2019-10-16T16:11:20+00:00',
    'timeStamp': '2022-07-09T19:41:08+00:00',
    'publishToEcom': 'false',
    'categoryID': '3',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '2',
    'manufacturerID': '0',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '185',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}, {
    'itemID': '5',
    
.....a ton more results....
```

Here's the tail end of the last "item" in the single page response.

```
    'categoryID': '168',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '0',
    'manufacturerID': '2',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '186',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}
```

And here's the transition from that last item in page one to the first item in page 2, as appended:

```
            }, {
                'amount': '14.99',
                'useTypeID': '3',
                'useType': 'Online'
            }]
        }
    },
    [{
        'itemID': '105',
        'systemSku': '210000000105',
```

So instead of the transition being:

```
}, {
```

it's:

```
    },
    [{
```

Is that what is breaking Panda's ability to convert the data to a .csv? If so, how could I go about fixing it? I can't post the entire results as it contains private information. I hope what I've given is enough to understand the issue, if not please indicate what specific areas I can edit so they are able to be provided.

Comment: If the data is paginated, the json will probably be structured as some kind of list, or perhaps a dict with unique keys. So you need to load all the json pages *as objects*, and join them all together to form a single list/dict (i.e. using list.extend / dict.update, or whatever). Once you have that, you can convert it back to json and save it to disk.

Comment: To answer this requires knowing how the "paginated" data is structured — which you have not indicated.

Comment: I've made an edit. I changed up how I was doing it, but am getting a new error now. I hope I've provided more useful information this time.